# Exchange / Suppress delivery notices, out of office when sent to distribution list

Tags: exchange, distribution-lists

An internal distribution list (DL) has some 300 or so members. It is used as a mailing list. When sending to this DL, it is typical to get a dozen of out-of-office replies and a a few "Mailbox full" delivery notices. As this DL is organization wide, it does not matter that somebody hasn't received the mail or is out of office.  This is very annoying, especially when replying from blackberry and receiving 80+ messages of "John's mailbox is full and Sue is having fun snowboard in Alps"
How to suppress OOO and Delivery Notices when sending to a to a specific  DL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting for the Out Of Office.

```
Distribution Group Properties > Advanced Tab > Send out-of-office message to originator
```

I don't think you can do anything about the "Mailbox full" notices, other then disable them complete is the same panel. (Do Not Send Delivery Reports)

Comment: Can the "Do Not Send Delivery Reports" setting be per DL?